# How can I binding data to ComboBox and rewrite items template?

Tags: wpf

I wanna make a combo box which likes the photoshop to show all the fonts in computer and display it.
[image]

I should display the font name, the sample of the font, so I have to rewrite the style of the items.

I wrote the code as this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,0,10">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ComboBox></ComboBox>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

But visual studio reports an error:
[image]

How can I solve it and custom a combo box by my self? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sample. Edited according to owner's comment.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <local:GetFamilyName x:Key="getName"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource getName}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sample" TextAlignment="Right"
                               FontFamily="{Binding}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Convertor Code

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class GetName : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value as FontFamily)?.FamilyNames.Values.First();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I find that if can bind the itemsource to  ItemsSource="{x:Static m:Fonts.SystemFontFamilies} , I can get the font list. But now the question is how can I bind it in the datatemplate?

Comment: @102425074 Then you need to change binding for two `TextBlock` and write a new converter to get first family name form `FontFamily.FamilyNames`.